# shared_ptr cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, cygwin

I am using Eclipse Juno, and Cygwin C++ compiler (latest version).
I wanted to declare shared_ptr (haven't worked with this pointer before) as..

Included the memory header file.

```
int main(){

std::shared_ptr <int> pointer;

return 0;
}
```

but the compiler cannot resolve `shared_ptr`. To solve this problem I have done the following steps:

1. properties->c/c++ build->settings->tool settings->Miscellaneous-> other flags->  -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11
2. properties->c/c++ build->settings->tool settings-> Cygwin C++ linker-> libraries(-l)-> add (-pthread)
3. C/c++ General->path and symbols->Symbols-> Add- **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** into "Name" and left "Value" blank.
4. C/c++ General -> Preprocessor include Paths, Macros->Entries-> CDT user setting entries->Add-> Preprocessor Macro (from dropdown manue)-> Name: __cplusplus, Value:201103L-> Apply
5. Index-> Rebuild
6. Restart Eclipse

Unfortunately, could not solve the problem. It would so nice of you if I get help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you `#include <memory>`, in your actual code?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Which version of gcc do you have.

Comment: For point-1 instead of -std=c++11 try "-std=c++0x"

Comment: 1. Cygwin DLL 2.5.2,  setup-x86_64.exe, this version i have

Comment: 3. shared_ptr could not be resolved

Comment: 4. Ya, I am sure that I included #include <memory>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include <memory>` in order for the compiler to know about `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: in addition on cygwin you need to call the proper std : `g++ -std=c++11 -o shared shared.cc`

Comment: That depends on the compiler version. Newer gcc's use C++14 as the default.

Comment: Tested on cygwin as the question refers. `gcc version 5.4.0` without the std the example fails as reported.

Answer (score 0):

Dear everyone who answered to my problem,
I was able to solve the problem. :-)
After I deleted the old __cplusplus value(199711L), the compiler was able to know shared_ptr.